# Object.fromEntries is not a function (Node.js error with Express)

Tags: node.js, express

I am developing a Node.js app, and it's working great on the local server. However on my Cpanel server (running Node 14.20.1) I am getting this strange error:

```
"Object.fromEntries is not a function"
```

The stack trace is

```
    at app.post (/home/joshgncd/riverbank.app/auth/index.js:435:5) \\ this is just the line that prints the error
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/joshgncd/nodevenv/riverbank.app/auth/14/lib/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/joshgncd/nodevenv/riverbank.app/auth/14/lib/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/joshgncd/nodevenv/riverbank.app/auth/14/lib/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/joshgncd/nodevenv/riverbank.app/auth/14/lib/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/joshgncd/nodevenv/riverbank.app/auth/14/lib/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (/home/joshgncd/nodevenv/riverbank.app/auth/14/lib/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
    at next (/home/joshgncd/nodevenv/riverbank.app/auth/14/lib/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
    at cors (/home/joshgncd/nodevenv/riverbank.app/auth/14/lib/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:188:7)
```

The function calling it never calls Object.fromEntries:

```
app.post('/auth/notion/action', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const data = req.body
    const tokens = users[req.query.email].notion_tokens
    const notion = new Notion({
      auth: tokens.access_token
    })
    let response = await notion.search(data)
    res.send(response)
  } catch (err) {
    console.trace(err.message)
    res.status(400).send(err.message)
  }
})
```

Can someone help figure out why this is happening?

I also am sure it's not a Notion API error as I replaced `let response = await notion.search(data)` with an Axios HTTP request and still got this Object.fromEntries error.

Comment: Which is line 435 of `riverbank.app/auth/index.js`? Are you absolutely sure your server is running Node 14? `Object.fromEntries()` has been supported since v12

Comment: Line 435 is simply "res.status(400).send(err.message)". Cpanel displays "started (v14.20.1)" so I was pretty sure that wasn't the case. However it may be that the server is taking longer to update Node, as I switched from v10 recently. I will check in an hour or so.

Comment: Are you looking at the actual file on the server or your local copy?

Comment: It's the server file. I ran node --version on the server and it is running v14.

Comment: So you're actually looking at the file itself via SSH or in CPanel somehow?

Comment: How are you running the app? Sorry if this is obvious but I don't know CPanel. Do you have some sort of reverse proxy directing web traffic to it? If so, how is that configured?

Comment: It's a built-in feature of the server that I'm using a visual UI to manage: https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/cpanel/setup-node-js-app/. I'm using Namecheap, whose customer service didn't help at all. The file I'm viewing through Cpanel's "File Manager," which is a file browser of everything on the server. Sorry I can't be more specific; it's probably an issue with the server setup but I'm not dealing with that operation firsthand.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by using this libary: [polyfill-object.fromentries](https://www.npmjs.com/package/polyfill-object.fromentries)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).